# Problem with Makefile compilation on Ubuntu, -lhidapi-libusb library

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, module, compilation

I have a slight problem with a Linux module compilation. No matter where I put a -lhidapi-libusb library reference in the make command, the module just refuses to compile. I know I'm doing something wrong, please help me, if you have some time.

Thanks

```
obj-m += light.o
all:
make -lhidapi -libusb -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules 
clean:
make -lhidapi -libusb -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD)
```

Output:

```
fatal error: hidapi/hidapi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <hidapi/hidapi.h>
```

Comment: Sorry for posting an image, my bad. Corrected the problem. Separting libusb did not help (maybe i did it wrong?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do doesn't make sense, and will not work.

libusb and HIDAPI are userspace libraries. They cannot be used within a kernel module.

Comment: so i have to use another method of interacting with the device driver and passing a status report?

Comment: Possibly? It's not clear what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually install the hidapi header library:

```bash
$ sudo apt install libhidapi-dev
```

https://github.com/libusb/hidapi#installing-hidapi